# which java turn when i exe ant, PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, ant, certificate, pki

I try to find out why my script ant fail

```
<get src="${https://my.wsdl}" dest="/my.wsdl" />
```

I read lots of forums for this error

> SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I know it is certificates but I put in cacerts in all my java (
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79, C:\eclipse-jee-indigo-win32\eclipse\jre\lib\security, C:\Windows\java\lib\security)

I don t know how to debug to find which java ant used when I choose `"Run in the same JRE as the workspace"`, I renamed all this java (javaOO) to find which it use but I have always the same result:

> [echo] JAVA_HOME is set to = 1.7.0_79
>   [echo] glassfish.home.3
>   [echo] C:\glassfish3\glassfish/lib
>   [echo] Java Version via Ant: 1.7
>   [echo] Java Version System Prop: 1.7.0_79
>   [get] Error getting https://my?wsdl to ..        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:

Even when I delete JAVA_HOME, the same result. I can't conclude something.

I don't known if i can put crt et pem in cacerts because there is not keystore in in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\security? Usually I put pem et srt in keystore

I turn in circle since two days

Comment: Look at the installed JREs in eclipse. Eclipse shows all paths. When launching ant you can decide which JRE use. If you are really using a JRE where you think cacerts is updated then ensure cacerts contains the root certificate of https://my?wsdl. List contents with keytool or using GUI KeystoreExplorer

Comment: thanks for your answer in fact  i found it was tha java in C:\eclipse-jee-indigo-win32\eclipse\jre\lib\security . my ant program in eclipse doesn t care java home or jre in eclipse